# Xticks overlapping

Tags: python, matplotlib

The pH 6.50 and pH 6.52 overlap with each other because they are too close. Is there a way to just make gaps between the bars wider?

```
pH = [ 4.5 ,  5.  ,  5.1 ,  5.4 ,  5.6 ,  5.7 ,  6.  ,  6.3 ,  6.5 ,
        6.52,  6.7 ,  6.8 ,  6.9 ,  7.  ,  7.1 ,  7.2 ,  7.3 ,  7.4 ,
        7.5 ,  7.6 ,  7.8 ,  8.  ,  8.1 ,  8.2 ,  8.3 ,  8.5 ,  8.7 ,
        9.  ,  9.2 ,  9.6 ,  9.8 ,  9.9 , 10.  ]
pH_count = [  8,   3,   1,   2,   3,   1, 109,   2,   9,   1,   2,   4,  11,
       119,   6,  16,   2,  30,  27,   1,  43,  71,   1,   2,   1,   8,
         4,  27,   9,   3,   2,   2,  50]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,4))

ax.bar(pH, pH_count, width = 0.1)
ax.set_xticks(pH)
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
ax.set_ylabel("count")
ax.set_xlabel('pH')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like your problem is just that your x-axis is not sampled in a regular interval. `matplotlib` is putting the x-array at their respective values between 4.5 and 10, so increasing the space between the bars would mean altering the x-axis values. If you just wanted to change the size of the ticks, you could use `ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize= <value>)`

Comment: An option is to use seaborn: `sns.barplot(x=pH, y=pH_count, ax=ax)`. Seaborn would space the x-ticks evenly.

Comment: Depend on what you are trying to say with the graph. For example, you have ph difference of only 0.02 (6.5 ,6.52). Is that a difference that is significant? If not consider bucketing the values and accumulating the counts.

Comment: if you want 4.5 to 5.0 to be five times as far apart as 5.0 and 5.1, then this is the right way to plot things.  If you want them evenly spaced despite the value of the pH, then convert the list of numbers to a list of strings